# How to Run script with admin rights to change execution policy

Tags: powershell, admin

See below script:
I need to  launch this script with admin rights embedded inside of the script to set execution policy to unrestricted and then at the end of the script set it back. From what I've found so far this is either not possible or very difficult to do. I'm hoping there is an easier way to do this. The users that will be running this script do not have admin rights on their PC's so they will not be able to elevate and manually run from inside of powershell.

```
Stop-process -Name OUTLOOK -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
Stop-process -Name communicator -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
Stop-process -Name lync -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
Stop-Process -Name UcMapi -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
Stop-Process -Name skypehost -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
Stop-Process -Name searchprotocolhost -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force

$OstPath = "c:\users\$([environment]::username)"+ "\AppData" + "\local" + "\Microsoft" + "\Outlook" 
$ost = get-ChildItem $OstPath | where { $_.Extension -eq ".ost"}  
$ost | remove-Item -force

Start-Process Outlook


if (Test-Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\office15\lync.exe')
{
    Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\office15\lync.exe'
}
Else
{
   write-host "Lync is not installed"
   if (Test-Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office Communicator')
   {
        Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office Communicator\communicator.exe'
   }
   Else 
   {
           write-host "Communicator is not installed"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$GBL_Username = "Here type your username"
$GBL_Password = ConvertTo-SecureString –String "Here type your password in plain text" –AsPlainText -Force
$GBL_Credential = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $GBL_Username, $GBL_Password

Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\office15\lync.exe' -Credential $GBL_Credential
```

And use the variable `$GBL_Credential` with the second part (the execution of Office Comunicator)

A problem with this: the credential will show in plain text and, if someone try to edit the script with notepad, PowerShell ISE or other program, they can will see the passsword.

Have a good day.

Comment: I would start this answer with: `No mater what you do, don't do this:`

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the script, there's no need to elevate. If this is only to overcome the ExecutionPolicy than your approach is wrong. ExecutionPolicy is there to prevent users run untrusted scripts. So far your script is one of those.

Correct way of doing it would be to sign your script with the certificate and set your ExecutionPolicy to Allsigned on all computers. Users will then only be able to run the signed scripts from now on.

If this is not possible, I see 2 options:

1. Users copy contents of the script and paste it into the powershell window
2. You set ExecutionPolicy to unrestricted. Keep in mind that users will still need to elevate if they try to do something serious, but for this script elevation is not necessary.

So all in all, ExecutionPolicy is there to prevent exactly what you are trying to do, so do not expect it will be easy to overcome. It's also not something that you turn off and on. You should think of what is acceptable for you and set it to appropriate level in your environment.